# Passing information to JavaFX Button handle() routine

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx

I have the following code to set up a Button in JavaFX 8:

```
        Button button = new Button("target name");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Button pressed = (Button)event.getSource();
                // next target name is the title of the button
                handleClick(pressed.getText());
            }
        });
```

I would like to pass some information to the `handleClick()` routine.  In this case I have a String that is a "target name" and `handleClick()` is a method that knows what to do with that.  Right now I'm passing that information by making it the name of the Button.  Is there a better way?  For instance, what if I wanted to pass two pieces of information?  Or, what if the info I want to pass is not a String?

The `handle()` routine only accepts an `ActionEvent` parameter.  I can't find anything in `ActionEvent` that would help me here.

One idea I had: Maybe I could write my own `SmartButton` subclass that extends Button, and include in that subclass some additional info that is passed in at the time the `SmartButton` is constructed (so in the subclass I would only implement an extra constructor and one or more new getters/setters).  The `handleClick()` routine would then have access to that information via getters called on `(SmartButton)event.getSource()`.

This seems like a common UI programming issue.  What is the best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this additional information coming from? In the code snippet you posted, calling `getSource()` is redundant, because you know the source of the button *must* be the button declared above. So you can reduce the whole thing to `button.setOnAction(event -> handleClick(button.getText()));`. If you define `handleClick` to take additional parameters, you can similarly pass them in. It's not clear what you need here.

Comment: @James_D Ah, you're right, it works to pass local variables directly to handleClick.  I thought a variable that's local at the time the Button was constructed would be out of scope inside `handle()`...

Comment: As long as it is `final`, or effectively final, it is in scope in the lambda or anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code snippet you posted, the event handler is only associated with the button created in the first line. Furthermore, since it's an anonymous inner class you know you only have the one instance of that class, and consequently that event handler cannot be associated with any other control. So your code is completely equivalent to

```
Button button = new Button("target name");
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        handleClick(button.getText());
    }
});
```

or, using lambda expressions:

```
Button button = new Button("target name");
button.setOnAction(event -> handleClick(button.getText()));
```

You can basically always do this, even if the data needed to handle the button press is not the text in the button. Consider a calculator app (restrict it to integers for simplicity). You would likely have some variable storing the current value displayed:

```
private int value ;
```

and then you want a bunch of numeric buttons which "append" their own value to the current value (so if the current value is 1 and you press "2", the current value should be 12, etc):

You would just need

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 9 ; i++) {
    Button button = createButton(i); 
    // place button in UI...
}
```

with

```
private Button createButton(int buttonValue) {
    Button button = new Button(Integer.toString(buttonValue));
    button.setOnAction(e -> value = value * 10 + buttonValue);
    return button ;
}
```

Some variation on this idea will always give you what you need.